# Microsoft Band SDK for Windows Store 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, microsoft-band

The [documentation](http://developer.microsoftband.com/docs/MicrosoftBandSDKPreview.pdf) for the Microsoft Band SDK Preview claims it supports WinRT 8.1 for Windows applications but after downloading the NuGet package (1.3.10219-preview) into my Windows Store C# project I ran into some major roadblocks:

First, when I tried building after immediately adding the NuGet package I got the following compilation errors:

```
Payload file 'C:\...\packages\Microsoft.Band.1.3.10219-preview\lib\portable-win81+wpa81\Microsoft.Band.Store\Tiles\AddTilePage.xbf' does not exist. 
Payload file 'C:\...\packages\Microsoft.Band.1.3.10219-preview\lib\portable-win81+wpa81\Microsoft.Band.Store\Microsoft.Band.Store.xr.xml' does not exist.
```

Second, the documentation says to add the following invalid XML into the `Package.appxmanifest`:

```
 <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
   <Device Id="any">
     <!-- Used by the Microsoft Band SDK Preview -->
     <Function Type="serviceId:A502CA9A-2BA5-413C-A4E0-13804E47B38F" />
     <!-- Used by the Microsoft Band SDK Preview -->
     <Function Type="serviceId:C742E1A2-6320-5ABC-9643-D206C677E580" />
   </Device>
 </m2:DeviceCapability>
```

Third, the `Microsoft.Band.Store.dll` assembly doesn't contain a `BandClientManager` so I can't get a reference to my band as described in the documentation.

I was able to work around the first and second issues by copying the missing files from the wpa81 NuGet package and adding the `m2:` prefix to all XML elements respectively, but I have no idea how to get around the third problem.  Poking around with .NET Reflector it looks like the functionality may be there locked away in some internal classes but I don't see anything in the public types.

Is there anyway to get this working on Windows or does it only work on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial Microsoft Band SDK Preview (1.3.10219-preview) was focused on Windows Phone and so does not contain NuGet targets specifically for Windows Store applications. It allows the bundling of Band-related logic within a portable library that targets both Windows Phone and Windows Store--notwithstanding the packaging issue you encountered--but does not allow the creation of IBandClient instances on Windows Store.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I figured as much.  Was hoping maybe there was some work around to get it working on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The new SDK now supports Windows Store Apps :)

-------OLD------

I was able to access the BandClientManager in my Windows Store App using a little bit of reflection, and could access everything in the SDK except subscribing to sensor data as that part uses the [RfcommDeviceService.Device](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.devices.bluetooth.rfcomm.rfcommdeviceservice.device.aspx) type which is only accessible on Windows Phone.

Could also connect using the socket APIs, but then there is the matter of reading and writing data and interpreting it :P

[image]

I've spent some time with the SDK, and got tired of having to connect the band to my phone and deploy the app to the phone for testing/debugging, so I ended up creating a simulator that wraps the SDK. I guess you could do something similar for the missing bits. The simulator uses sockets to send data that is either pre-recorded (using a file- and will then animate the movements) or by manipulating the 'band' with the mouse/touch as you do with the Windows Phone emulator.

Obviously these are only temporary solutions or for development purposes until a Store compatible SDK is released.

[image]